# Spring Cloud Client - What version to use in dependency management section?

Tags: spring-cloud

All,
I'm having an issue using Spring Cloud 1.0.1 that I'm not having in Spring Cloud 1.0.0.  Specifically, clients are no longer able to reach the config server.

I have a Spring Cloud Config Server up and running using 1.0.1.RELEASE.  In building the client, I'm referring to the documentation here:  http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/docs/1.0.1/spring-cloud.html#_client_side_usage.  This refers to a parent with version 1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, which is not released.  So my first question is, is the documentation incorrect here when referring to this version?  I would expect the version to be 1.0.1.RELEASE.

Assuming it is, I find that my client connects to the config server perfectly when using version 1.0.0.RELEASE of spring-cloud-starter-parent.  But if I switch this to 1.0.1.RELEASE, the client no longer finds the config server (keep in mind, the config server is using 1.0.1.RELEASE).  There is no error, the console logging simply does not emit any references to the CompositePropertySource that one ordinarily sees when the client finds the server.

Is there a change from 1.0.0.RELEASE to 1.0.1.RELEASE that requires some extra setting that isn't described?

Answer (score 1):

1. you need to use the `1.0.1.RELEASE` version of the parent.
2. in the 1.0.1.RELEASE the `spring-cloud-starter` does not include the config client, so you need to specify the `spring-cloud-starter-config` dependency explicitly.

Comment: you are correct, that is the solution.  Thanks.  This also answers a nagging question I had on the back of my mind as to why I never needed to define a client side dependency for the config client.